# Named callout Null in http request with named credential - What would cause it?

Tags: callout, httprequest, namedcredentials, calloutexception

I am making a callout and getting the error

"System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "XXX" might not exist."

When I inspect the log, it appears that the Named callout has all values as null. I don't understand why since we already set up the named credential in Salesforce.

I am attaching both the named credential and the error log.

```
  HttpRequest reqData = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();
    
    String subscriptionApi = 'callout:xxx/https://xxx.com/api/v2/customers/' + custId + '/subscription_for_items' + params;
    System.debug('Complete request ' + subscriptionApi);
    String method = 'POST';
    reqData.setHeader('Authorization', 'Username xxxxx');
    reqData.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    reqData.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');
    reqData.setTimeout(25000);
    reqData.setEndpoint(subscriptionApi);        
    reqData.setMethod(method);

    
    HTTPResponse response = http.send(reqData);
    System.debug('response ' + response);
    return response;
```

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT: After incorporating Keith's suggestion the values are now not null. I am now getting this
[image]

Comment: One thing is that your `callout:xxx/` should replace the `https://xxx.com/` as the named credential identifies the endpoint server. May not be the only problem though...

Comment: Thanks Keith. That worked since the values are not null anymore. I am now getting bad request error Status 400. Thoughts?

Comment: PS You don't need to set the 'Authorization' header when using Named Credentials.

Comment: An the 400 error, make sure to output all info in the response including the body e.g. `JSON.serializePretty(response)`. And if you have any access to the service you are calling, look for errors at that side too.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I removed the basic but the error didnt go away. But it turns out that one of the parameters which was using epoch date needed to be divided by 1000. It has finally worked!

Comment: Well done for figuring it out! I've experienced the same pain making such calls.